# Can I do a fillet curve in WPF?

Tags: wpf, drawing

My understanding of a fillet curve is that given three points where the middle point is associated with a radius, one can draw a curve from the two extreme points using a circle defined by the radius.

Is there support for this in WPF or would I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes and no.

**NO:** There is no native function DrawFilletCurve(p1, p2, p3);

**Yes:** You can draw anything you want with Path. There is native support for [cubic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.beziersegment.aspx) and [quadratic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.quadraticbeziersegment.aspx) Bezier curves.

You may also find something helpful in [Live Geometry](http://livegeometry.codeplex.com/) project, from MS ace [Kirill Osenkov](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/).

Comment: Guess I need to figure out whether I can implement a fillet curve using beziers...
anyways, +1 for the Live Geometry link, great Silverlight sample :)

Comment: And yes, correct answer since you are... well... answering my question correctly :)